# Hide bottom tab navigation at one page

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I will be very happy if you help me. I am making mobile app wiht react native.  And in this app i am using react navigation. I have file app.js that contains code for bottom tab navigation - home.js. And in home.js i have 2 classes. 1 class is main and second class is for button navigation. I want to hide bottom tab navigation when i navigate to second page(second class).I tried tabBarVisible: false, but this does not work. Help me, please. Code:

```html
// app.js
const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Home:{
    screen:Home,
    navigationOptions:{
      tabBarLabel:'Главная',
      tabBarIcon:({tintColor})=>(
        <Icon name="ios-home" color={tintColor} size={24} />
      )
    }
  },

  Courses:{
    screen:Courses,
    navigationOptions:{
      tabBarLabel:'Courses',
      tabBarIcon:({tintColor})=>(
        <Icon name="ios-school" color={tintColor} size={24} />
      )
    }
  },
  Editor:{
    screen:Editor,
    navigationOptions:{
      tabBarLabel:'Editor',
      tabBarIcon:({tintColor})=>(
        <Icon name="ios-document" color={tintColor} size={24} />
      )
    }
  },

},{
  tabBarOptions:{
    activeTintColor:'#db0202',
    inactiveTintColor:'grey',
    style:{
      fontSize:3,
      height:45,
      backgroundColor:'white',
      borderTopWidth:0,
      elevation: 5
    }
  }
});



export default createAppContainer(TabNavigator);
```

```html
// home.js

import React from 'react';
import { Font } from 'expo';

import { Button, View, Text, SafeAreaView, ActivityIndicator, ListView, StyleSheet, Image, Dimensions,
ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation'; // Version can be specified in package.json
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons'
import Courses from './Courses'

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Home',
  };

      const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    return (

      <SafeAreaView style={styles.MainContainer}>
      <ScrollView
      >
<ListView
         dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
         renderSeparator={this.ListViewItemSeparator}
         renderRow={rowData => (
           <>
      <Text
               onPress={() => {
                 /* 1. Navigate to the Details route with params */
                 this.props.navigation.navigate("Articles", {
                   otherParam: rowData.article_title,
                 });
               }}
             >
               {rowData.article_title}
             </Text>
              
           </>
         )}
       />
       </ScrollView
       >
</SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}


class ArticleScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation, navigationOptions }) => {
    const { params } = navigation.state;

    return {
      title: params ? params.otherParam : '',
    };
  };

  render() {
    const { params } = this.props.navigation.state;
    const article_title = params ? params.otherParam : '';


    return (
        <Text>{article_title}</Text>
    );
  }
}


  const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
    {
      Home: {
        screen: HomeScreen,
      },
      Courses: {
        screen: Courses,
        navigationOptions: {
       header: null,
    }
      },
      Articles: {
        screen: ArticleScreen,
      },
    },
    {
      initialRouteName: 'Home',
    }
  );




  const AppContainer = createAppContainer(RootStack);

  export default class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return <AppContainer />;
    }
  }
```

Comment: I'm not that familiar with `react navigation`. If no one will answer you, I can try to help (I have some experience with rn + expo) if you'll create a [snack](https://snack.expo.io) for that.

Comment: @Mosh Feu ohh yes, thanks. I have already asked this question, no one helped me. I will create snack.

Comment: And I hope I could help :)

Comment: @Mosh Feu https://snack.expo.io/@rapprogtrain/basic-tabs-v3 - there is error with class/function. I do not know how to solve it because when i run in my editor is all ok. But this is the code (i have added only the most important things). Thanks very much for your help!!!

Comment: Have you tried setting `tabBarVisible` in the `static` `navigationOptions` of the component you want to hide the tab bar in?

Comment: @zaytrix yes i have tried

Comment: Why are you creating an app container in Home if you've already created one in App?

Comment: @zaytrix app,js is for bottom tab navigation but home.js is for navigation in this page. Because i have button that navigates from home to Courses and home to article page

Comment: App container is only necessary for the top level navigator, which in your case is the tab bar. Your Home can just export the stack navigator. As far as what the issue is, since Home is a stack of screens, you need to set tabBarVisible on the navigationOptions of the stack itself, so you'll need a way to detect what is the current route. I'll post an answer with the way to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working snack: https://snack.expo.io/ByS8igvC4

The key thing here is this function, `getActiveRoute`, which recursively searches for the name of the currently active route, necessary in the case of nested navigators:

```js
const getActiveRoute = route => {
    if (!route.routes || route.routes.length === 0 || route.index >= route.routes.length) {
        return route.routeName;
    }

    const childActiveRoute = route.routes[route.index];
    return getActiveRoute(childActiveRoute);
}
```

Usage in the tab navigator:

```js
const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Home: {
      screen: Home,
      navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        tabBarLabel: 'Home',
        tabBarVisible: getActiveRoute(navigation.state) !== 'Articles'
      })
    },
    // ...other screens
  },
  {
    // ...navigator options
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I give you a simple example with `createBottomNavigator` in which you have 3 tabs, and the Third one has another Stack like `createMaterialTopTabNavigator`

```js
export const FooterStack = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    First: {
      screen: FirstScreen
    },
    Second: {
      screen: SecondScreen
    },
    Third: {
      screen: ChildStack,
      navigationOptions: ({ navigation: { state: { index } } }) => ({
        tabBarVisible: index === 0 || index === 1 // Here is the Magic, you just have to pass the index in where you do not want to show the createBottomTabNavigator bar
      })
    }
  }
)
```

Here is my `ChildStack`

```js
export const ChildStack = createMaterialTopTabNavigator(
  {
    FirstChild: {
      screen: FirstChildScreen // this is the index 0, so it will be not visible the BottomTabBar
    },
    SecondChild: {
      screen: SecondChildScreen // this is the index 1, so it will be not visible the BottomTabBar
    },
    ThirdChild: {
      screen: ThirdChildScreen
    }
  }
);
```